# Error in create a outlook object

Tags: c#-4.0, outlook-addin, runtime-error

When I in visual studio 2010 on a windows 7 x64 machine wants to
integrate with Outlook 2010 I'll get this error:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException was unhandled by user code
  Message=Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {0006F03A-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80080005 Server execution failed (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80080005 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE)).
  Source=mscorlib
  ErrorCode=-2146959355
  StackTrace:
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingServices.AllocateUninitializedObject(RuntimeType objectType)
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Activation.ActivationServices.CreateInstance(RuntimeType serverType)
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Activation.ActivationServices.IsCurrentContextOK(RuntimeType serverType, Object[] props, Boolean bNewObj)
       at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
       at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache)
       at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache)
       at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
       at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)
       at SpatialExcelAddIn.MapBrowserUI.AddAttachment() in C:\Userdata\Projects2010\ExcelAddin\ExcelAddin-branch\UIandExcelLayer\MapBrowserUI.cs:line 105
       at SpatialExcelAddIn.MapBrowserUI.emailToolStripMenuItem_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Userdata\Projects2010\ExcelAddin\ExcelAddin-branch\UIandExcelLayer\MapBrowserUI.cs:line 86
       at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.RaiseEvent(Object key, EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.HandleClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.HandleMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.FireEventInteractive(EventArgs e, ToolStripItemEventType met)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.FireEvent(EventArgs e, ToolStripItemEventType met)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mea)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.MenuStrip.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
  InnerException:
```

I have added a reference to the Outlook version 14 component and are
using the code:

OL.Application app = new OL.Application(); <-- this cause
the error

It only happens when Outlook is running, if I stop Outlook application
and run the code again, i works just fine.

,please advice!

Comment: This is just a guess, and I'm not familiar with C#, but is there a way to check for a running instance of Outlook first?